# Error while activating new python environment

Tags: python, environment, conda

I've created a new python environment for python 3
[Environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsTz2.png)
But I'm unable to activate it using command "activate newEnvName" 
[Error while activating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ2Bc.png)
WPA Failed: missing mandatory parameters /srv/db

what am I missing ? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some other activate.exe in your `PATH` environment variable. Try the following:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate python3Env
```